# How do I delete/remove a shell function?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have done this:

```
$ z() { echo 'hello world'; }
```

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 303, accepted):

```
unset -f z
```

Will unset the function named z.  A couple people have answered with:

```
unset z
```

but if you have a function and a variable named z only the variable will be unset, not the function.

Comment: Note that this applies to [POSIX compliant](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#unset) shells, not just Bash.

Answer (score 5):

In Zsh:

```
unfunction z
```

That's another (arguably better) name for `unhash -f z` or `unset -f z` and is consistent with the rest of the family of:

- `unset`
- `unhash`
- `unalias`
- `unlimit`
- `unsetopt`

When in doubt with such things, type `un<tab>` to see the complete list.

*(Slightly related: It's also nice to have functions/aliases like `realiases`, `refunctions`, `resetopts`, `reenv`, etc to "re-`source`" respective files, if you've separated/grouped them as such.)*