# Remove function definition (unalias equivalent)

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I'm currently building a program which adds to the current user's shell depending on the project he's working on, by defining per-project aliases and functions. These aliases and functions may and will certainly have the same name like for instance `cdproj`, which would `cd` to the project's root.

I would like to remove previously defined aliases and functions when changing project (before (re)defining aliases and functions for the other project. I know I can remove an alias with `unalias` in both bash and zsh, but how would I do the same for a function?

Comment: Interesting thing is that this is not totally a duplicate. The question is not about bash only. There is a reference to `zsh` too.

Comment: @VictorYarema More interesting, Zsh tag was recently added to that question (direct edit by high-reputation users), making this a valid duplicate.

Comment: This happend to `grep`. I couldn't decide whether it was funny or not. I couldn't grep for possible locations.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
unset -f my_function
```

will remove (or unset) the function my_function

Comment: `-f` is for function, as opposed to upsetting a regular variable. Explained in this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/245409/1695680

Comment: `unset` works in zsh, seems the `bash`-style.

Answer (score 30):

`unfunction my_function` in `zsh`

Perhaps, I'm a bit late in this good old '15, but this feature persists.

Comment: Nice!  This is more consistent with `unalias`, though perhaps a bit unwieldy.

Comment: It is never too late. Thanks.