# Temporarily Unsetting Bash Function

Tags: bash, function

It's been [well documented](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6807188/1944335) that is's possible to `unset` a Bash function. Consider this function:

```
ls() {
    echo 'Executing';
    # Call to original ls
}
```

which can be unset with `unset -f ls`.

I want to build a wrapper function which will temporarily unset a function, call the original function, then reset the function back. I want to do this to execute code surrounding a programing without having to rename my function arbitrarily.

I've thought of several possible solutions to this problem, none of which I'm particularly satisfied with.

#### Method 1: Simply linking to the original executable

```
ls() {
    echo 'Executing';
    /bin/ls $@;
}
```

While this would achieve the desired effect, it's not ideal because it is dependent of knowing where the original `ls` (in this case) is located ahead of time. This would break on any platform that didn't have `ls` in `/bin`

#### Method 2: `source` the function definition again once the method finishes executing

```
ls() {
    echo 'Executing';
    unset -f ls;
    /bin/ls $@;
    source ~/.bash_functions;
}
```

#### Method 3: Store the state of the function (attempted)

I couldn't get this one to work, but it seems like I should be able to capture the function, save it, then unset and reset the function, like so:

```
ls() {
    echo 'Executing';
    SAVED=`which ls`;
    unset -f ls;
    /bin/ls $@;
    ls=$SAVED;
}
```

---

So, how can I unset a function to call the original then reset it in Bash? Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> unset a function, call the original function, then reset the function back.

Don't bother un-setting/re-setting the function, use the `command` builtin instead :

```
>alias pwd='echo nope'
>pwd
nope
>command pwd
/home/Aaron
```

Comment: Wow! I've been living in the terminal for some time now, and I had no idea this existed. Thank you so much!